# Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed ERROR WHEN CONNECTING XBOX ONE CONTROLLER TO RASPBERRY PI

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to connect an xbox one controller to my raspberry pi 3B+ via the built in bluetooth. I am finding the controller in the bluetooth, but when I go to connect I get these messages:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 9C:AA:1B:DD:62:14
Attempting to connect to 9C:AA:1B:DD:62:14
[CHG] Device 9C:AA:1B:DD:62:14 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 9C:AA:1B:DD:62:14 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 9C:AA:1B:DD:62:14 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 9C:AA:1B:DD:62:14 Connected: no
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you were "trying to connect an xbox one controller to my raspberry pi 3B+ via the built in bluetooth"? As you tagged [python], do you have any code?

Comment: I was following this website: https://pimylifeup.com/xbox-controllers-raspberry-pi/      and then I got stuck with the error that I posted above.

Comment: Have you made any advances on this issue?